# Diablo 3 is coming - train with us!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, contests

> *Diablo III* is here! Therefore **the training period has ended**, and [it's time to do battle for real](http://diablo3acts.com/). Winners for this contest have been selected. Congratulations to:
>
> - [fredley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3610/fredley) for asking [What is a ladder character?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64631/16718)
> - [EBongo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/21619/ebongo) for asking [Is there a way to see loot on the ground?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/65062/16718)
> - [Krazer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/15772/krazer) for answering [Can I fight the 4 Ubers in single player or non-ladder battle.net?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64806/16718)
>
> For our three winners, please email me at lauren [at] stackexchange [dot] com to claim your prize! For those who didn't win a prize this time around, check out [our Diablo 3 contest](http://diablo3acts.com/) for another chance to play Diablo and win lots of cool stuff!

The third chapter in the *Diablo* series will be released on May 15th. Many of you are waiting in eager anticipation for another chance to battle the minions of Hell. When the time comes, will you have what it takes to defend Sanctuary?

The next two weeks will be dedicated to helping you prepare for your fight against the forces of evil that are ever-present in the world of *Diablo*. Train with us by playing *Diablo* and *Diablo II*. When you have questions, [ask them here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and tag them accordingly.

To reward you for your hard work and bravery during this training, we will raffle off prizes. Everyone who posts a question or answer during the training period that has a score of 5+ will be entered into a drawing.

**Rules:**

- Tags: Your post must be tagged either [diablo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo), [diablo-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-2), or [diablo-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-series) to count.
- Time frame: Your post must go up during the training period to count. The training period started at the time this meta post went up and will go until May 14th at 11:59 pm UTC.
- Eligibility: The contest is open to current and new gaming.stackexchange.com users. Everyone is eligible regardless of geographic location; however, we sometimes come across issues with international shipping that make it very difficult or impossible to send prizes to people who live in certain areas. If this happens to be the case, Stack Exchange will work to find a mutually agreeable solution, but we cannot guarantee that we will always be able to make international orders work.
- Prizes: To be entered into the drawing, you must post a question or answer during the training period that has a score of 5 or more when the training period is over. Every post you make that meets these specifications will earn you one entry. Three names will be drawn, and those three people will get to choose one prize from the options below.

Prizes: If you are one of the 3 lucky winners, you will have your choice of one of the two options below.

Option 1: A copy of *Diablo III* - purchased on the day of the release

[image: Diablo III box art]

Option 2: A *Diablo III* gift package including

- A *Diablo III* t-shirt ([men’s](http://us.blizzard.com/store/details.xml?id=1100000342) or [women’s](http://us.blizzard.com/store/details.xml?id=1100000343))
- [*Diablo III*, Book of Cain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1608870634) (Hardcover)
- [*Diablo III* Gaming Mouse Pad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0075AM5RY)

[image: Diablo III t-shirt, Book of Cain, mouse pad]

**Edit:** In response to comments below, I've added [diablo-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-series) to the list of tags that count for this contest. Thanks for pointing that out everyone.

Comment: [The D3 beta ends tomorrow.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4905211/The_Diablo_III_Beta_Draws_to_a_Close-4_17_2012) :/

Comment: One question we've had is - is there a grant upcoming for D3 (& other games, potentially)?  A prize of a copy of D3 in this contest seems a bit weird if there's other opportunities to get it.

Comment: @IanPugsley thanks for letting me know - removed that.

Comment: @agent86 yes, there is an upcoming game grant, and you'll have the opportunity to win Diablo 3. I will post the details today or tomorrow, and you should know whether you've won the game grant before this contest is over, that way you can decide which prize you want :)

Comment: Should [tag:diablo-series] also be included as it ostensibly refers to both both Diablo and Diablo 2?

Comment: @MBraedley - you're welcome to include the tag diablo-series, but it must also be tagged either diablo-1 or diablo-2 for specificity.

Comment: Will the copy of D3 be digital?  If it's physical, getting it ordered the day of would be less that ideal for a proficient question-asker.  They'll be behind the big question push for the game, and likely they'd want to play right away.

Comment: @MatthewRead, I guess it'll be digital... [it would be far easier](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56430/14) ;)

Comment: @JuanManuel Well they do use Amazon for a lot of things.

Comment: @Lauren: The reason I brought it up was because I saw a [recent question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64619/1351) that was retagged to just diablo-series after being initially tagged with all three games.  I get the feeling that'll be par for the course.

Comment: @MBraedley, I retagged for now... feel free to flag for this issue at least until we have an official answer from Lauren.

Comment: @MBraedley I definitely didn't make that edit because of the contest; I was trying to clean up the tags in good faith. I promise...

Comment: @StrixVaria: Wasn't saying it was malicious, but I'm thinking there'll be more questions that make sense to be tagged with just diablo-series in the next couple of weeks and we shouldn't exclude those questions from the contest IMHO.

Comment: I agree. The diablo-series tag should be fair game for the contest.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added tag diablo-series to the list. Thanks for pointing that out everyone.

Comment: if you recieve +5 on multiple posts, do you get multiple entries into the raffle and therefore increase your chances of winning?

Comment: @Ender From the post above: Every post you make that meets these specifications will earn you one entry.

Comment: Have winners been announced for this contest?  I know it just ended... Just curious.

Comment: @EBongo winners will be announced soon :-)

Comment: Congratulations to the winners :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that ended a long time ago.