# Arqade & SciFi Cross-site Topic Challenge: The Elder Scrolls

Tags: discussion, community-event

> ### The challenge has now begun!

The Arqade moderators have decided to do a [joint topic challenge](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13440/august-2021-topic-challenge-the-elder-scrolls) with our sister site, [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). The theme for this topic challenge is for the [the-elder-scrolls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-series)  of games, and will be active throughout the month of **August 2021.**

## What is a Topic Challenge?

A topic challenge is an optional community event where users are encouraged to post **high quality questions** (and answers!) matching a specific theme. They have a [long history on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work), and SciFi has been doing them [since January 2021](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13211/announcing-a-topic-challenge-program-for-sff-se). Arqade has never done before, but we have done something similar with the Stack Exchange run [Diablo 3](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/diablo-3-is-coming-train-with-us) and [Mass Effect 3](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/mass-effect-3-missions-on-gaming-se) contests several years back.

## How do I participate?

Just post questions for The Elder Scrolls either here on Arqade, or over on SciFi. If your questions are gameplay focused, post them here on Arqade. If they're lore focused, then post them over on SciFi.

On Arqade, the tags involved in this challenge are:

- [the-elder-scrolls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-series)
- [the-elder-scrolls-arena](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-arena)
- [the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall)
- [the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind)
- [the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion)
- [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim)
- [skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition)
- [the-elder-scrolls-blades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-blades)

## Why would I want to participate?

The purpose of the challenge is to just have fun, with the added bonus of (hopefully) generating some high quality content on the site. At the end of august we'll post an answer recognizing the two questions posted in August with the **highest score and views.** There's no prize aside from bragging rights, but the moderator team will likely hand out a bounty to a handful of exceptional answers posted throughout the challenge.

## Is this going to become a regular community event?

**Maybe**. The moderator team decided to participate in this as part of our efforts to [have more community events](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14681/what-type-of-community-events-would-you-like-to-see/14685#14685). The Screenshot contest has gone fairly well, and when the SciFi mods approached us about doing a joint community event, it seemed like a great way to try out topic challenges. If this challenge is received well by the community, then the moderator team will look into making this a regular occurrence.

In short, consider this to be a trial run of topic challenges of Arqade. If it goes well, we'll likely do more in the future.

Comment: This is a great idea!

Answer (score 5):

I'm curious as to why Elder Scrolls I-III and V are included, but number IV (Oblivion) isn't. Was this a deliberate omission, or was it excluded by accident?

Comment: Because its bloom has blinded too many already.

Comment: Because I forgot about it. I've updated the post.